# Setting fill style in polygon in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers

I have created a polygon using Vector layer in OpenLayers 3 now I have to fill that polygon with red color. But I cannot do this using style option in OpenLayers 3.

Any one have any idea how to do this?

Comment: From this [**link**](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0-beta.1/apidoc/ol.style.html#ShapeOptions), I'm **guessing** to fill it would be something like: `var fill = new ol.style.Fill({color: 'rgba(50, 100, 150, 0.50)'});`. But don't quote me on this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must define a **ol.styleStyle** object, which again consist of an **ol.style.Fill** and an **ol.style.Stroke** object. In the OL3 documentation you must unclick the "Stable only" field in the upper right corner to see the full documentation.

```js
_myStroke = new ol.style.Stroke({
   color : 'rgba(255,0,0,1.0)',
   width : 1    
});

_myFill = new ol.style.Fill({
   color: 'rgba(255,0,0,1.0)'
});

myStyle = new ol.style.Style({
   stroke : _myStroke,
   fill : _myFill
 });
```